# Hypernym for "for sale", "for rent", etc

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

What do you call the category whose members include "For Sale," "For Rent," "For Lease," etc.?

To put it another way, how would you fill in the blank:

> When we see a signage for an apartment for sale, we say that the apartment's _________ is "For Sale".

Comment: Could you be more specific? Category of what? Phrases?

Comment: Indeed, being a bit more specific would help, because the first thing that comes to mind is **signs put on objects**, which is probably not what you are looking for. If you are simply looking for "what does the preposition _for_ mean, and how is it used?" I think you need to thoroughly rephrase your question...

Comment: Do you mean _Property Status_ ? _Tenure type_ ?

Comment: @oerkelens OP is looking for a name for the category which includes "renting", "leasing", "selling", etc. A proper word which means status-of-ownership-and-usage-rights or rights-transfership-situation, etc. My guess is he's a programmer looking to name a field or a database column.

Comment: @DanBron: the edit made it clearer, indeed. If I were a betting man, I'd back up your guess :) I think that _status_, as mplungjan proposed, might do fine.

Comment: "Property status", "sale status" or "ownership status" come to mind.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think "Tenure Type" might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comment into answer:

- Property Status
- [Tenure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_tenure) type

> (Land) tenure is the name given, particularly in common law systems, to the legal regime in which land is owned by an individual, who is said to "hold" the land 
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_tenure)</sub>